# UISearchBar: different style depending on iOS version

Tags: ios, iphone, ios6, ios7, uisearchbar

I wan't to display a UISearchBar in clear black if running on iOS < 7 and in clear white if iOS == 7.

In Xcode graphical layout at the moment the search bar is black.

Is there a simple way to do that once for all search bars in the application?

I'm pretty new to iOS developing, so please be patient and cristal clear :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change your settings using code like this:

```
if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 7.0) {
    // iOS >= 7   
} else {
    // iOS < 7    
}
```

If you have many bars in your app, you can subclass `UISearchBar` and use this code in there.

Comment: Thanks, i've subclassed UISearchBar and put the control in the initWithCoder initializer. Then i changed all my search bars to be the custom class.